# How do I install gnuconio on linux

Tags: gcc, ncurses

I downloaded the gnuconio on this site (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnulinuxconioh/)

I unzipped the zip he jerou me the following files:

```
bash-4.2$ ls
Doxyfile  READ-ME.txt   conio.c  conio.ppr     constream            titledoc.html
Makefile  READ-ME.txt~  conio.h  conio_test.c  constream_test.cpp+
```

I read the readme.txt

```
GNUCONIO 0.1 2012

Thanks for downloading the opensource and GPL license gnuconio-0.1 library.
With this you can use colors, getch and others graphical functions based
on the conio.h library, using the #include "conio.h" normally, in Windows
or Gnu Linux systems.

In Gnu Linux systems only copy the conio.h file to your programs folder
to use it. You will need the NCURSES library to work on linux (libncurses-dev).

In Windows you will need to compile the conio.c file, and use the conio.o file
in your compiler library list. Tested on the compiler Code::Blocks.

To start the conio use any function, except the printf and scanf. To end the
program, make the text color == background color, and use the clrscr()     function.

Have Fun !
```

I do not know how to do what it says in the readme.txt.
I am compiling my project directly in the terminal, I'm using Slackware 14.1 and the ncurses library is installed.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you really not know how to copy the file `conio.h`? Or do you not know how to get the NCURSES library installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments to the other answer, what is missing is the library linked in.

Make sure `ncurses-dev` (or similarly named package) is installed. This will install a file `/usr/include/ncurses.h` (and a lot of other stuff).

Then you have to run the following commands:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o some.o other.o files.o here.o -lncurses -o progname
```

Ths first just compiles your `main.c` file, this should give no errors. The second one gathers your resulting `main.o` object and others you need, and links them with the ncurses library to give the `progname` executable.

In any case, if you are doing this for Linux only, better learn how to use ncurses and its ilk directly. The package you are refering to is old (last update in 2012), is not present in the Fedora repository (that usually means it is not up to snuff), and pastes a Windows specific interface over the perfectly usable and well-tested Unix interface.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just have to put the file named *conio.h* in the folder of the source of your program, this is as simple as the README says.

Actually, what is not working when you are doing this ?

Comment: I am importing the libraries in this way:


    #include <ncurses.h>
    #include "conio.h"

conio.h is in the directory of the program.
I did as mandated in the README but the following error:



bash-4.2$ gcc main.c -o main.o
/tmp/ccPiwIEF.o: In function `initconio':
main.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `initscr'
main.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `start_color'
main.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `init_pair'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I could not put all the error because it has character limit here.